# Memory usage option is missing from diagnostic tools in Visual Studio 2022 Community

Tags: visual-studio

I am unable to view memory usage in Visual Studio 2022 Community edition.

According to the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/memory-usage?view=vs-2022), there should be a memory usage option in the diagnostic tools.

[image]

However, my installation does not appear to have this option.

[image]

I've tried checking out the **Settings** for Diagnostic Tools and also reading every setting in **Tools > Options > Debugging > General**.

I've also run the VS installer with the profiling tools option checked.

How can I view memory usage in Visual Studio 2022 Community?

Comment: @BerkeKaanCetinkaya I uninstalled and reinstalled VS. That worked. When you run the VS installer, try to select as few options as possible (add-ons like python, game development, etc). I've noticed that selecting lots of options interferes with the VS installation.

Comment: Adding the minimum amount of optional components is what got me into this.".Net profiling tools" is leaving Memory Usage out by default for some asinine reason.

Answer (score 1):

Doing a "Repair" fixed this issue for me.  In Visual Studio Installer, press "More" and then "Repair".

In my case, I had installed a number of VS components for a fresh install and later added and removed a couple where the profiling tools was one of the ones I added.  I think it got confused, but the repair seems to have rectified it.